# Errors when trying to pass comma through multiple macros

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to pass a comma through multiple levels of macros, but the preprocessor doesn't like that...

```
// This is just simplified, in reality I have some other variadic function which will
// stop upon encountering the -1 and APPEND_COMMA() may add more args (like `a, b,`)

#include <stdio.h>

#define MACRO_EX(val) printf("%d %d", val -1);

#define MACRO(val) MACRO_EX(val)

#define APPEND_COMMA(a) a,

int main() {
        MACRO(APPEND_COMMA(1));
        return 0;
}
```

What exactly is causing the compile failure here?

```
test.c:10:8: error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
        MACRO(APPEND_COMMA(1));
              ^
test.c:7:26: note: expanded from macro 'APPEND_COMMA'
#define APPEND_COMMA(a) a,
                         ^
test.c:5:29: note: expanded from macro 'MACRO'
#define MACRO(val) MACRO_EX(val)
                            ^
test.c:3:9: note: macro 'MACRO_EX' defined here
#define MACRO_EX(val) printf("%d %d", val 0);
        ^
test.c:10:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MACRO_EX'
        MACRO(APPEND_COMMA(1));
        ^
test.c:5:20: note: expanded from macro 'MACRO'
#define MACRO(val) MACRO_EX(val)
                   ^
2 errors generated.
```

The comma seems to be expanded in the called macro, so that `MACRO_EX(a,)` is called, which is not what I want.

---

I found some workaround for this by using `__VA_ARGS__`:

```
#define MACRO_EX(...) printf("%d %d", __VA_ARGS__ -1);
```

But I'd really prefer to pass the comma cleanly through all the macros up to the variadic function call and use cleanly named macro parameters [like I intended in my original code].

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Try `-E` option in your `gcc` compiler.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The difference is, that the comma isn't introduced inside the macro call, but it's brought in via another macro. That way I can pass it up to `MACRO()`, but somehow it then gets expanded.

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild nope, it's a preprocessor failure, it stops there. As said, I know what happens, I'd like to have a way to pass it like parameters, not like some __VA_ARGS__...

Comment: you don't want `#define MACRO(val) printf("%d %d", val -1);`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY no, there's happening more in that step. It's just simplified for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to guarantee a comma will be passed "cleanly" through macro parameters is to wrap it in parentheses:

```
#define APPEND_COMMA(a) (a,)
```

Now the result of `APPEND_COMMA` will always be a single preprocessor argument.

The obvious problem with this is that it produces `printf("%d %d", (1,) -1);`, which is now valid preprocessor code, but no longer valid C code. This is rectified by inserting an "unpack" step into the definition of `MACRO_EX`:

```
#define IDENTITY(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define MACRO_EX(val) printf("%d %d", IDENTITY val -1);
```

`IDENTITY` will unpack the contents of `val`, assuming `val` is a parenthesised argument list, during `MACRO_EX`'s rescan step.

What about situations where `val` might not be parenthesised, because it doesn't contain a comma? The answer is to not let them arise. Arguments that *might* contain a comma should *always* be wrapped, so they can always be safely unwrapped at the final point of insertion. Macros need to be designed with the knowledge of whether they anticipate single tokens or lists*. This is the preprocessor's equivalent of a static type constraint: macros like `MACRO` require an argument of type list, not of type atom (and the calling macros similarly need to be written with the correct type signatures in mind); on those occasions when they need a single argument only, pass them a single-element list.

<sub>* It is technically possible to design a macro that tests whether its argument is parenthesised and branches on the result, but you're getting into dark magic territory there. Stick to fixed types for clarity.</sub>

Comment: Wrapping and unwrapping is definitely a nice idea. Thank you for the tip.